# Resolve Bean Injection Programmatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I would like to find a way to elect programmatically a Candidate between different implementation present on the bean factory, at Spring Container Level.

With Profiles I can achieve that simply like this

I Have the following Profiles "CH" and "IT" and I want that if a Bean Profiled with IT is there, then will fallback to default.

Given those classes:

The Default Implementation

```
@Component
public class DefaultMapper {
     public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Map Default");
    }
}
```

The Swiss Implementation

```
@Component
@Profile("CH")
public class SwissMapper extends DefaultMapper {

    @Override

    public void doSomething() {

        System.out.println("do something swiss");

    }

}
```

The Italian Implementation:

```
@Component
@Profile("IT")
public class ItalianMapper extends DefaultMapper {
@Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("do pasta");
    }
}
```

Now if I run it with     `@ActiveProfiles("IT")` it throws a NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException, which is fair enough, since the Default is not profiled, and it will be registered without any further attention by the container.

Some Consideration:

if I add     `@Profile("default")` to     `DefaultMapper`  this will work until I have another default bean has a subclass profiled ONLY with CH.

Default Implementation of another Bean:

```
@Component
@Profile("default")
public class DefaultParser {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Parse Default");
    }
}
```

Then the Swiss implementation (No Italian is available, or better said the default fits for Italian):

```
@Component
@Profile("CH")
public class SwissParser extends DefaultParser {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Ässe Ässe");
    }
}
```

Now if I run it with     `@ActiveProfiles("IT")` it throws a No BeanDefinitionException, which is fair enough, but not that fair, since the "default" is not chained as ActiveProfiles and for IT i have no implementation. the CH profile here will work since has a profiled implementation for each default class.

Said That
I would like a better way to cover this scenario without:

- Having to define on the Default Classes such     `@Profile({"default","IT", "<all other profiles which have NOT a specialized implementation"}` , or     `@Profile("!CH")` where I exclude those profiles which have a specialization.
- `@Primary` I think is not a solution, because on the `DefaultMapper` I have to Specialization which will be marked as     `@Primary` and the container doesn't like it at all

Then
I would like to solve this where I can decide for ALL the injected Classes, when the resolution of the Beans is ambiguous then I would like to programmatically decide (in container) which implementation I would like to pick. I think an Annotation likewise to @Profile, i.E. @Candidate("CH") will suit compared to a value set in application.properties in a i.E. nationality.cantidate=CH. Something like:

```
public class MyExtension extends UnknowSpringType {
    @Override
    Object resolveAmbigousDependency(final Context ctx, final Resolution resolution) {
        final List<Class> clazzes = resolution.getResolvedClasses();
        for (final Class clazz : clazzes) {
            if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(Candidate.class) && clazz.getAnnotation(Candidate.class).getVaue().equals(candidateApplicationPropertyValue)) {
            return clazz;
        }
        return getDefaultImplementation(clazzes);
    }
}
```

I've done in the past Something similar with CDI SPI extension which is elegant, and also I could cover this in another way with `@Specializes` from CDI, but I cannot find the same easy way on Spring (I don't have so much experience on it), BeanFactory?  [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-extension-factory-postprocessors)?

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark all your specific Parsers as @Primary this will make sure Spring autowires this one instead of the default one which is not marked as @Primary. When no specific Parsers exist for the chosen profile it will fall back to the non @Primary default component.

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html

```
@Component
public class DefaultParser {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Parse Default");
    }
}
```

```
@Component
@Primary
@Profile("CH")
public class SwissParser extends DefaultParser {
@Override
public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Ässe Ässe");
}
```

Comment: on the demo seems to work i had tryied something like this and wasn't working i will give it another try.

`
@Primary
@Profile(value = { MigrationProfiles.DEFAULT })
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface PrimaryProfiles {
    @AliasFor(annotation = Profile.class, attribute = "value")
    String[] value();
}
`

Comment: Fortunately i am stupid, in my scenario with primary i had forgotten to take out @Primary on the default Class. Thanks for bringing me again to this world.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Comment: OK , it works, my Default was clean, instead my AliasFor annotation was good for nothing, it wont work like this :( i need to put Primary and Profile, cannot aggregate annotations, at least those one...

Answer (score 0):

You can activate multiple profiles, CH and IT and your implementation will fail.

It is a internationalization problem.

Comment: This is an example, and anyway it should fail if you run multiple countries.